# The managed beans were not be deallocated even after the sessions is invalid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lifecycle

I've got a JSF application being served by Tomcat 6, and each session may gets viewScoped  beans allocated to it in the "session" scope as a managed bean . The problem is that the memory used to store this bean doesn't EVER seem to be getting deallocated, even after the sessions has spent hours in the idle state.

Is there any way to force Tomcat to deallocate this memory after a session has been idle for a certain length of time (like say, 10 minutes)? If not, how about a way to manually deallocate this memory programmatically? Or is one of the features of a "managed bean" in the "session" scope that it will persists in memory until the server shuts-down, no matter what?
Thanks in advance!

But the viewScoped beans may not be deallocated. Because If clicked on a link on the expired page, The logs in tomcat console shows that the UIViewRoot on the serverside is still alive. The logs:
**beforePhase-RESTORE_VIEW 1
afterPhase -RESTORE_VIEW 1 Time:3
beforePhase-RENDER_RESPONSE 6**
And the memory of the server process didn't decline a little. If the server runs a relatively long time. The application's response is so slowly and seems not robust such as the paginator doesn't work and so on.
Even When the server shutdown,the console printout :
**Waiting for 16 instance(s) to be deallocated**

Are there anybody know about this?

Comment: This isn't the responsibility of JSF/PrimeFaces. It's the responsibility of GC. Run a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your session scoped managed beans do not get deallocated because the session hasn't timed out.  You need to specify the acceptable timeout for your session in the deployment descriptor file (`web.xml`).  The following example is in minutes.  After 10 minutes the session will be invalidated and your session scoped beans should be destroyed.

```
<session-config>
      <session-timeout>10</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

Comment: I know this parameter,and the Session is timeout also after the X minutes.You can see I had edit my answer.